# JDBC and sqlserver connection string - do I have to include port number?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Regarding use of JDBC with Microsoft SQL Server.

Do I have to supply the port number as part of the JDBC connection string?

It seems this is optional if the default of 1433 is in use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017

Am asking as the ADO connection strings I have used with SQL Server do not include port numbers?

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: What aspect of "default" do you not understand?

Comment: It does say "The default is 1433. If you're using the default, you don't have to specify the port, nor its preceding ':', in the URL."

Comment: Gord ...Fair call .... but I was thinking of considerations like:   Maybe usage of 1433 is very, very common?  Maybe ADO would have issue if the port is not 1433 and no port is supplied via the ADO connection string?   What if a port other than 1433 is being used and you don't want to pass the port number via JDBC connection ?

Comment: @AllanF If you don't want to use a named instance, you need to have the SQL Server Browser service running. I'm not sure if that also applies for the situation of a non-default port.

Comment: My previous comment should have read "If you want to use a named instance" (without the _don't_)